# MySQL Join multiple tables on common column with no order of importance

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a large database with many tables. Some of these tables may contain an `email` field. They are all the same type of varchar(255). What I want to be able to do is join all of the tables with an email column together and get a list of all the unique emails on the database.

The problem I have is there will be multiple tables with that column so I need it to be high performance. The second problem is that afaik, joining tables together means that they must have a common value from the first table to the joined table.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT
    email
FROM
    table_1
LEFT JOIN
    table_2
USING (email)
LEFT JOIN
    table_3
USING (email)
```

However, I want to be able to get all of the emails from all the tables regardless of if they exist in the other table.

Would it be quicker to do a union select on all the tables in a temp table and select distinct from that?

I need to be able to do this over lots of tables (10+) with thousands to millions of rows over them potentially. If needed, I will set the email columns up as an INDEX.

Thanks

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` does not require identical values in other tables, but it is computationally expensive as db has to process `N^T` result rows, where N is number of emails and T is number of tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want unique emails from all the tables, including emails that only occur in one table, you should use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table_a
UNION SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table_b
UNION SELECT DISTINCT email FROM table_c
...
```

Comment: I see, looks like I will have to as my left join query didnt work as intended. Because of the scale of the tables though, will UNION be quicker then UNION ALL and a GROUP BY email?

Comment: @Ozzy you will probably need to benchmark it to see which is faster.

Comment: I reckon the simplest query would be the easiest for db engine to optimise. That being said benchmarks are important, as unions often get much less attention than other db features. Different implementations may vary :) Conceptually, db has to go through each table's email index (or whole table if there's no index) and keep a map of already selected emails. If your data set is truly huge, it may be faster to stream all emails (without distict constrain) out of db and distinctify result in your user code (on another machine).

Comment: As far as my experience with MySQL goes, 'simple' and 'able to run efficiently' have little correlation. In this case both solutions require the same rows to be read, the only difference (if any) would be the specific internal algorithm used in distinct and group by.